# System Monitor not running

Tags: networking, grub2, dpkg

When I click on system monitor nothing happens. Then I tried to run the command `gnome-system-monitor`. I get the error message:

```
internal error, please report: running "gnome-system-monitor" failed: cannot find installed snap "gnome-system-monitor" at revision 100: missing file /snap/gnome-system-monitor/100/meta/snap.yaml
```

I tried to remove the package  by running the command:

```
snap "remove gnome-system-monitor".
```

Now it ends with the following error message:

```
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for linux-image-4.15.0-55-generic (4.15.0-55.60) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-55-generic
cp: cannot stat '/etc/udev/udev.conf': No such file or directory
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/udev failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-55-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
```

I also have another problem every time I turn on my computer I always have to  restart my network services. Could you help me with that as well?

I would appreciate help to resolve the issue.

everything went well. After I restarted my computer again and pressed Esc to see what I had at the Grub menu I was left with linux-image-4.15.0-55-generic and linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic. what happened to the linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what happened to break your system. The missing file `update-initramfs` is looking for is:

```
# see udev.conf(5) for details
#
# udevd is started in the initramfs, so when this file is modified the
# initramfs should be rebuilt.

#udev_log="info"
```

You can easily create it with `sudo -H gedit /etc/udev/udev.conf` and pasting in lines above.

Then reinstall the system monitor snap with:

```
sudo snap install gnome-system-monitor
```

Comment: **+1** as it answers the question, but this system is borked: re-install would be easier...